# Stale Asset - Hanami does not update the edited files

Tags: ruby, sass, hanami

I'm using Hanami with sass as preprocessor, but when I make changes in some .scss file and refresh the page the changes don't load, the **public/assets/*file*.css** is not updating. For update I have to delete the file...

Does anyone know why this happens?

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'bundler'
gem 'rake'
gem 'hanami',       '0.7.3'
gem 'hanami-model', '~> 0.5'

gem "sass"
gem 'pg'

group :test do
  gem 'minitest'
  gem 'capybara'
end

group :production do
  # gem 'puma'
end
```

application.rb

```
...

assets do
        ...
        # Stylesheet compressor
        #
        # Supported engines:
        #
        #   * :builtin
        #   * :yui
        #   * :sass
        #
        # See: http://hanamirb.org/guides/assets/compressors
        #
        # In order to skip stylesheet compression comment the following line
        stylesheet_compressor :builtin

        # Specify sources for assets
        #
        sources << [
          'assets'
        ]
      end
```

Comment: It's a bug, take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/hanami/assets/issues/54) on `hanami/assets` repo

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to upgrade to the latest Hanami version? As of today it's `0.9.2`.